# quadratic reduced forms

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question about a proof of a theorem of reduced quadratic forms. Let me explain it!

I'm going to denote the form $f=aX^2+bXY+cY^2$ as $f=(a,b,c)$. The theorem I want to prove says:

***Each form $f=(a,b,c)$ is equivalent to a form $f'=(a',b',c')$ such that $|b'|\leq |a'|\leq |c'|$. The form $f'$ is said reduced form of $f$.***

I follow the proof till one critic moment. I'll show you the proof and I'll show you my problem.

**Proof.**

We take $a'\neq 0$ the smallest integer number represented by $f=(a,b,c)$, it means: $\forall m\in Z, m\neq 0$ such that $f\rightarrow m$, we have that $|m|\geq |a'|$.

We take $\alpha, \gamma\in Z$ such that $f(\alpha,\gamma)=a\alpha^2+b\alpha\gamma+c\gamma^2=a'$. We have that $a'$ is the smallest integer number represented by $f$, so $m.c.d(\alpha,\gamma)=1$. So that, we can choose $\beta,\delta\in Z$ such that $\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma=1$.

Let's $P=\begin{bmatrix}{\alpha}&{\beta}\\{\gamma}&{\delta}\end{bmatrix}$. We have that $P\in SL(2,Z)$; so the matrix $P^T \begin{bmatrix}{2a}&{b}\\{b}&{2c}\end{bmatrix} P$ is the matrix of a form $f''=a'X^2+b''XY+c''Y^2$ which is equivalent to $f$.

Let's $Q=\begin{bmatrix}{1}&{-n}\\{0}&{1}\end{bmatrix}$. We transform $f''$ by the matrix $Q$ and we obtain $f'=a'X^2+(b''-2a'n)XY+(a'n-b''+c'')Y^2=a'X^"+b'XY+c'Y^2.$ (*My problem and doubt come from here, although I'm goint to explain it after!!!*).

We observe that $f'$ has $a'$ as first coefficient. We are going to show that we can choose $n\in Z$ such that

$-|a'|\leq b''-2a'n\leq |a'|$, which is the same that $|b'|\leq |a'|$.

Doing the division, there exists uniques $q,r\in Z$ such that $b''=2|a'|q+r, 0\leq r\leq 2|a'|$.

We pick $sgn(a)=\frac{|a|}{a}=\left \{ \begin{matrix} 1 & \mbox{if } a>0
\\ -1 & \mbox{if }a<0\end{matrix}\right. $.

If $0\leq r\leq |a'|$ we define $n$ by the formula $|a'|q=a'n$, i.e., $n=\frac{|a'|}{a}q=sgn(a)q$. From here we obtain that $b'=r\leq |a'|$.

If $r>|a'|$ we define $b''=2|a'|(q+1)+(r-2|a'|)$. We have that, $-|a'|=|a'|-2|a'|<r-2|a'|<0<|a'|$, so we define $n$ by the formula $|a'|(q+1)=a'n$, i.e. $n=sgn(a')(q+1)$. So $r-2|a'|=b''-2a'n$, which implies that $|b'|\leq |a'|$.

Now, by the choice of $a'$ and because $f'\rightarrow c''$ we have that $|a'|\leq |c''|$. So that, $f\rightarrow c''$. Selected $n$, it's enough to coose $c'=c''$ (*WHY? IT'S MY DOUBT!!!*), $b'=b''-2a'n$.

I've been searching in diferent books but I've just found the proof for positive forms, not general as in here. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your post is very long. You might get more people answering your question if you (1) improve your title to *specifically* and *concisely* state what you're asking, and (2) try to state more concisely your question. I doubt many people will want to read through all that just to find out where you are confused. Try finding out exactly what confuses you and then just stating that instead of copying the proof here.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the transformation. Given form $\langle r,s,t \rangle$ which refers to $$ f(x,y) = r x^2 + s x y + t y^2,$$ the Hessian matrix is
$$ 
H = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2r & s \\
s & 2 t
\end{array}
\right)
$$
You may see the term Gram matrix, some authors call $H$ the Gram matrix, some call $H/2$ the Gram matrix. [Gram was a real person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%B8rgen_Pedersen_Gram). [So was Hesse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_Hesse). [The author who won the Nobel Prize in Literature was different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Hesse).

Next you take
$$ 
Q = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -n \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
This should have given
$$ 
Q^T H Q = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2r & s - 2 r n \\
s - 2 r n & 2 r n^2 - 2 s n + 2 t
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which means the quadratic form with coefficient triple
$$\langle r, \; \; s - 2 r n, \; \; r n^2 - s n + t \rangle$$ 
You already chose $r$ so that $r$ has the smallest absolute value when $(x,y) \neq (0,0).$

Important Caution: if the discriminant $\Delta = s^2 - 4 r t = w^2$ for some integer $w,$ this becomes false, as there is then an integer representation of $0.$

When $\Delta$ is not a square, $|r| \neq 0$ is minimal. We may choose $n$ so that $|s - 2 n r| \leq |r|.$ Finally,
$$ f(-n,1) = r n^2 - s n + t $$ is a value of the form. We already chose $r$ as the minimum possible, so
 $$ |f(-n,1)| = |r n^2 - s n + t| \geq |r|. $$

Let's see: for indefinite forms, this is not what we call reduced. The traditional Gauss-Lagrange reduced forms $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ are those with $ac < 0$ and $b > |a+c|.$ Zagier introduced a variant in his 1981 book on Zeta functions, $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ is Zagier reduced if $a > 0,$ $c > 0,$ $b > a + c.$ In both cases, we are requiring $\Delta = b^2 - 4 a c > 0$ but not a square.